# iPhone Write Bytes to Socket

Tags: ios, sockets

I have an outputstream in my app and I just want to write 3 Bytes to that stream.  Has anyone seen a good example?  Bytes are:

```
Byte command1 = 254;
Byte command2 = 108;
Byte command3 = 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: The "Streams Programming Guide" from the Apple Developer Library has good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the votes down jack-wagons.

I found an answer to my question from some example software another programmer posted.  Here is the example code:

```
Byte *commandBytes = malloc(3);
commandBytes[0] = (Byte)254;
commandBytes[1] = (Byte)108;
commandBytes[2] = (Byte)1;
[outputStream write:(uint8_t *)commandBytes maxLength:3];
```

Hope this will help someone out in the future.